# Java subList with list size as fromIndex and toIndex

Tags: java

So if I have a list of size 3, let's say [0,1,2] and I try to access list element with index 3 (list.get(3)), obviously it fails with an out of bounds exception. However, with the subList method, if I try:

```
list.subList(3, 3);
```

I get an empty list back as the result. According to the Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int). This method throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException for an illegal endpoint index value (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex). This means that if fromIndex == toIndex && toIndex == size, no exception will be thrown.

Intuitively, that seems like it should not be the case since you can't access the fourth element of a list if there are only three. So why does this work? Is it intended to fulfill some use case or is it an unintended side effect?

Comment: What implementation of List are you testing with?

Comment: I tried this for ArrayList

Comment: But you're *not* accessing the fourth element, so there is no problem. You're creating a sublist of the empty space after the third element. `subList(2, 2)` would be creating a sublist of the empty space between element 2 and 3. That's all good. Now `subList(4, 4)` would fail, because you can't get to the empty space after element 4, when there is no element 4.

Comment: It never hurts to take a peek at the original source code. [Here's ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.subList%28int%2Cint%29). Note that it appears that while `subList(3,3)` would work, `subList(4, 4)` should fail because `toIndex > size`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is plainly found in the [documentation you already linked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)). See the very first paragraph. In particular, note the parenthetical phrase (which I have bolded):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. **(If fromIndex and
>   toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.)** The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Since you passed subList the same value for `fromIndex` and `toIndex`, the List you get out of it will be empty, even if the indices are out of bounds of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this.

[Why not IndexOutOfBoundsException on List.subList(size, size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503862/why-not-indexoutofboundsexception-on-list-sublistsize-size)

> To contemplate the decision of API designers why they decided to do it
>   this way, we may take as an example String.substring(), which has very
>   similar (the same) constraints. Possibly to allow to select an empty
>   string/sublist? Only two exceptions will be thrown for this.

As you know, exceptions will be thrown in below case:

1. IndexOutOfBoundsException

   - if an endpoint index value is out of range
     (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)
2. IllegalArgumentException

   - if the endpoint indices are out of order (fromIndex > toIndex)

so, in your case
fromIndex = 3 which is not greater than the size(3). 
and also not greater than toIndex (3)

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?? spuriously, have you read OP's argument?

Comment: @CommonMan what is OP?

Answer (score 0):

I think it fulfills a use case where you may want to create a sub list of everything that was added to a list since a certain moment in time.

A use case I had was that of allowing a call back to add elements to a list I control, but if an exception is thrown, I'd like to remove all such elements:

```
List<T> events = ... ;
int offset = events.size();  // start offset for new entries

try {
  appender.accept(events::add);  // allow call back to add things
}
catch(Exception e) {
  // remove everything that was added in case of an exception:
  events.subList(offset, events.size()).clear();

  throw e;
}
```

Now, if the call back throws an exception before adding anything, the sub list I create will be empty, and the call to `clear` will have no effect. If `subList` had been more restrictive we would need another `if` here.

Edit: I suppose you can also use `subList` for defining points of insertion. For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("A");

List<String> subList = list.subList(1, 1);

subList.add("B");
subList.add("C");
subList.add("D");
```

By allowing `subList` to anchor itself in any position, you can add elements in any position using a plain call to `add` instead of the indexed one. `subList(0, 0)` would be the start of the list, while `sublist(list.size(), list.size())` would be the end of the list.

The sub list also expands itself when you use its `add` method, allowing easy removal of all added elements by calling `clear`. In the above example calling `clear` on the sub list at the end would leave only the element "A", regardless of where its insertion point was.