# Why not IndexOutOfBoundsException on List.subList(size, size)?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I was looking at the List.subList() method. I wondered why the following code doesn't throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add("A");
someList.add("B");
someList.add("C");
someList.add("D");
someList.add("E");

someList.subList(5, 5);
```

The docs says subList is subList(fromIndex, toIndex), where fromIndex is inclusive. Since my list.size() is 5, the indexes goes from 0 to 4. So if fromIndex is inclusive, shouldn't an Exception be thrown?

From the docs:

```
fromIndex - low endpoint (inclusive) of the subList
toIndex - high endpoint (exclusive) of the subList

IndexOutOfBoundsException - for an illegal endpoint index value (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)
```

I understand the boolean expression here. But shouldn't it be (... || fromIndex >= toIndex)?

What am I missing?

Comment: What about `subList(0,0)`?

Comment: It's not a problem to have a 0 length list, if `fromIndex` is always smaller than `toIndex` that wouldn't be possible, do you think that use case shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: They decided to build the spec that way, to allow for an empty subList if you had `fromIndex == toIndex`.  That was an explicit design decision they made, which has lots of advantages.

Comment: Yes, I think a 0 length list should be allowed. But if the fromIndex is included, doesn't Java try to fetch the item with something akin to someList.get(5)? In that case I would have thought the program would crash in the attempt.

Comment: I imagine a for-loop like situation with: `int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++`, but the loop never runs, since the condition is already false at the start. You could always check the source to make sure though.

Comment: `doesn't Java try to fetch the item` - Java doesn't fetch anything here. subList returns a *view* of the original list.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the implementation of `ArrayList` exactly what the criteria for IndexOutOfBoundsException are:

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    subListRangeCheck(fromIndex, toIndex, size);
    return new SubList(this, 0, fromIndex, toIndex);
}

static void subListRangeCheck(int fromIndex, int toIndex, int size) {
    if (fromIndex < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("fromIndex = " + fromIndex);
    if (toIndex > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("toIndex = " + toIndex);
    if (fromIndex > toIndex)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromIndex(" + fromIndex +
                                           ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
}
```

So you can see, since `toIndex == size`, exception is not thrown.

To contemplate the decision of API designers why they decided to do it this way, we may take as an example `String.substring()`, which has very similar (the same) constraints. Possibly to allow to select an empty string/sublist?

Also, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) confirms this assumption:

> (If `fromIndex` and `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.)

Comment: "_But shouldn't it be `(... || fromIndex >= toIndex)`?_"

Comment: @BoristheSpider Isn't that up to the API designers? Who are we to question them?

Comment: We are the users of the API, we are exactly the ones to question its designers.

Comment: @BoristheSpider OK, that was a little joke on my part. My point is, once the API is out, it cannot be changed. So the debate over, whether it is correct or not, seems a little pointless. At least here, on stackoverflow...

Comment: Of course the specification is correct. It would be incorrect if it were specified `... fromIndex >= toIndex)`.

Comment: @LewBloch I've included the code here because, I *believe* the question was edited since it was originally asked to point where it included the bounds, and they weren't included before.